# Scala quill "quote" not resolving

Tags: scala, quill.io

I'm trying to write database queries with quill for scala. ([Quill](http://getquill.io/))

I'm following what they're doing on quill's website but for some reason I cannot resolve the 'quote' method and a few others.

Any ideas?

[image]

Here's my build.sbt:

```
name := "Pop"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `pop` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( jdbc,cache,ws,specs2 % Test,
    "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1208",
    "io.getquill" % "quill-core_2.11" % "0.8.0",
    "io.getquill" %% "quill-jdbc" % "0.8.0")

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )  

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

Comment: try to run **activator clean-files**

Comment: Hmm, didn't seem to work

Comment: Try with `import io.getquill._` and after `ctx` declaration put `import ctx._`

Comment: Ah, adding the `import ctx._` did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Quill quotation introduction](http://getquill.io/#quotation-introduction):

> To create quotations, first create a context instance. Please see the context section for more details on the different context available.

So use `import ctx._` before calling `quote`, as documentation does, or `ctx.quote(ctx.query...)`. Failure to resolve `ctx.run` looks like an IDE problem to me: try to actually build the project.

Comment: ctx does not appear as a valid name for me. I am using quill 1.0.0 for cassandra. I still get the quote as undefined.

Comment: You need to create `ctx` first. For Cassandra, see http://getquill.io/#contexts-cassandra-contexts.